# Show gif image url on blackberry

Tags: blackberry

i've used BrowserField for display url.

```
String url ="http://www.wfaa.com/templates/mobile_indv_images?cpath=http://belo.bimedia.net/WFAA/weather/animated-loops/ssite/640x480/collin.gif"
```

my code is here,

```
        BrowserFieldConfig config = new BrowserFieldConfig();
        String userAgent = "BlackBerry" + DeviceInfo.getDeviceName() + "/" +    DeviceInfo.getSoftwareVersion() +" Profile/" + System.getProperty("microedition.profiles") +" Configuration/" + System.getProperty( "microedition.configuration") + " VendorID/" + Branding.getVendorId();
        config.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.USER_AGENT, userAgent);
        config.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.ALLOW_CS_XHR, Boolean.TRUE);
        config.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.ENABLE_GEARS, Boolean.TRUE);
        config.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE, BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE_POINTER);
        config.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.JAVASCRIPT_ENABLED, Boolean.TRUE);    
        config.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.ENABLE_COOKIES,Boolean.TRUE);
        config.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.USER_SCALABLE, Boolean.TRUE);

        myBrowserField = new BrowserField(config);
        myBrowserField.requestContent(url);
```

Its working on 9800, but when i check on 9930 simulator , the gif image not loading browserfield.

Some time it has show, sometime it has not show on 9930 device (os version 7). why its happen. how to show gif image url on 9930 device.

Comment: http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800505/800345/How_To_-_Display_an_animated_GIF.html?nodeid=1405903&vernum=0

Comment: Check it on device , I feel issues in loading of browser field into Simulator , but on device , it works fine. For 9800 Browserfield was also displaying in simulator too.

Comment: hi @ShashankAgarwal i've not device 9930. i've only 9800. but user put a commad, the gif images sometime loading sometime not loading.

Comment: Why don't you use code to show gif image programmaticly rather than using browser field.